# Find domain for function

Tags: functions

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both exist when $x$ is real number, then what are the required conditions for finding the domain for the function  $(f(x))^{(g(x))}?$ I am so much confused in signs. Take all four cases when $f$ and $g$ are positive or negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the reals exponentiation is only defined for non-negative bases, so you need $f(x) \ge 0$.  As $0^0$ is also not defined, you cannot have $f(x)=g(x)=0$.  Yes, you can raise negative numbers to integer powers, so you may want to consider that, but the discontinuity is bothersome.  You can also take odd roots of negative numbers, with the same discontinuity problem.

Comment: There's a question if for example we let things like $(-1)^{1/3} = -1$ slide as well.

Comment: @Jakobian:  Thanks.  I added that.

Comment: is domain for y = x^(1/3) is x non negative.

Comment: It would be seen as all real $x$.  In your original question $g(x)$ is presumably varying through the reals.  We would then say $f(x)^{g(x)}=g(x)e^{\log(f(x))}$ and demand that we can take the log of $f(x)$.  If you have $g(x)=1/3$ it is different because you can take the cube root of negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

When the exponent is a real, the base should be positive $>0$.

to define $x^\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a real, you need that $x>0$.

in this case, 
$$x^\alpha=e^{\alpha \ln(x)}$$

So, the domain of $f^g$ is 
$$\{x\in D_f\cap D_g \; : \; f(x)>0\}$$